# « Pour ce faire » ou « Pour le faire » ?

Tags: expressions, pronoms

Quand utiliser *pour ce faire* et quand utiliser *pour le faire* ?

NB: je ne suis pas sûr qu'on puisse dire « pour le faire ».

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La locution *pour ce faire* (qui s'emploie le plus souvent en début de phrase) signifie *pour faire cela*, tandis que *le* est un COD. Le pronom *cela* est plus distant, vague alors que *le* est précis.

> J'ai un devoir à rendre. Pour le faire, j'ai besoin de toi.
>
> Nous allons modifier les statuts. Pour ce faire, une assemblée générale sera organisée.

Answer (score 2):

*Pour ce faire* a un sens se rapprochant assez de *à cet effet*. *Pour le faire* n'est pas une locution (on l'emploie au même titre qu'on pourrait écrire "pour le terminer" ou "pour y arriver"): *pour* y signifie généralement "afin de".

Ce qui complique la chose est que "faire" a parfois dans ces constructions (particulièrement la première) un sens anaphorique pas très éloigné de la fonction d'un pronom, ce qui brouille.